# Do you get to keep Burn Cards over a level reset?

Tags: titanfall

When you reach level 50 you can do a reset of your level and unlocks. Do you get to keep your burn cards, or do you lose them too?

Comment: Doesn't the game tell you this?

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro  - The game does indeed tell you this.

Comment: @Ramhound Only at the regeneration screen, though.

Comment: @peper757 - regeneration is optional is it not?

Comment: I don't understand why I get downvoted, since imo the question is legit. At the moment I am level 36. If I would lose all my Burn Cards at the regeneration (which I am planning to do), I would know that I can spam them out until I hit Level 50. As peper757 said, the game tells me that I can keep then **at the regeneration screen** - not any earlier - however, this would be to late for me to know (since I wouldve kept my cards and lose them then). This is why I asked here, so I may know in time! But as usual people just like to downvote stuff...classic :-)

Comment: If you're already aware of regen before even reaching level 50, you'd surely already have the answer to this question. The game tells you all of the information that you know *and* the information you're asking for, all in the same screen when you first access the regen option, and you are given a choice to accept the regen there and then *or* hold off for later.

Comment: @Ramhound: The game does not force you to accept regen the moment you access the regen option for the first time, however you cannot progress beyond level 50 in any generation. The information is always there until you accept the regen. I know this because I just happened to regen a few hours before seeing this question.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro - No, I only had the information about the fact that you can do the regeneration, but not about the exact circumstances, which *is actually the reason I am asking*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get to keep you burn cards when you regenerate, plus the Titan chassis you've unlocked.